# make a vertical UIButton

Tags: iphone

is there anyway to have a UIButton display vertical, with the text reading down, instead of across? can you do it with IB or programatically? or will you have to photoshop to make a custom button?

cheers, Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Define the transform
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90 * (M_PI / 180));

// Initialize the UIView
UIView *myView    = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];

// Do the transformation
// in this case, rotate the UIView 90 degrees
myView.transform = transform;
```

[Source](http://www.crystalminds.nl/?p=1102)

Comment: um, where do i put this? and how to I put and action to it?

Comment: (to replicate the linking in IB)

Comment: just override the transform property of your IBOutlet UIButton